# Unable to create temporary folder: Unable to create temporary file /tmp/AndroidStudio319FirstRun

Tags: android-studio

I am a newbie in android programming. I can't build any app now suddenly. Even I can't update sdk. When i try to build, It says read only file system. Can anyone help?

Comment: please provide more details such as error,code...

Comment: you dont have write permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**for mac**

1. open terminal
2. sudo chmod -R 7777 /tmp/AndroidStudio319FirstRun
3. enter your system password

**for windows**

1. go to address bar

enter /tmp/AndroidStudio319FirstRun

2.right click anywhere, go to properties and give all write, read, permission to all users

Comment: Thanks, I figured the problem. It was sdk problem. Target sdk and compile sdk was set different.

Answer (score 0):

Running the .exe as administrator fixed the problem for me.